# NSMenuItem with NSVIew and Key/Mouse Events

Tags: cocoa, xcode4

I'm using a NSView within a NSMenuItem to allow me to change the padding and menu item height.

Unfortunately the view eats up the scroll wheel and key down/up events as describe in the documentation. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to pass these events back to the menu so it works like before where Key up/down would change the highlight selection, and the mouse wheel would scroll the list if it is too long. Has anyone come across a solution?

Edit:
This is not the same as the duplicate. I can already get the mouse up/down events for the custom view. My problem is that I have no way to pass these events back to the menu to do what it used to do.

For example how do I get the menu to scroll when the menu gets to long in response to a mouse scroll event?

How do I select and highlight the next item on the list in response to a Key Down event. Passing the event to the menu (or any of its superview/window) doesn't do anything, and there are no functions to do something similar that I can see/

Comment: Add this to your custom view and you should be fine:

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    return YES;
}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't answer my question. :) I already know how to get the mouse events. I want to know where do I pass them to the NSMenu so it did what it did before I used custom views.

Comment: i had a similar issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968959/intercepting-nsmenu-key-events